# Can't display images from models of django

Tags: django, image, model, display

Since I have faced this problem many times and couldn't find a solution, I need help

Here's my settings file. I've configured media root

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import django_heroku
import django
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'ws^pgf$%!=l8y#%^7anp$rl6*o4u9!86g-ba_uq9pcee=vc@13'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testimage.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'testimage.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

django_heroku.settings(locals())

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
```

And this is a simple models just to add and display images

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Images(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here's my views.py and the template

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from home.models import Images
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    images = Images.objects.all()
    context = {
        'images':images
    }
    return render(request,'home.html',context)
```

home.html

```
{%for i in images %}
<img src="{{i.photo.url}}" alt="">
{%endfor%}
```

Everytime I try to load that page, I always get this error:

```
[15/Feb/2021 11:57:12] "GET /media/20210129_205930.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2130
[15/Feb/2021 11:57:12] "GET /media/20201227_111422.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2130
```

I know it is telling that there is something wrong with the media path but I checked it all but can't find any wrong point. Please take a look

Comment: could you show your `urls.py` file.

Comment: Did you add the media urls to your urlpatterns? Check [Serving files uploaded by a user during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you haven't added media urls in your `url.py` file, so you can do something like this

```
# make your imports
from django.conf import settings 
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
      ....
]

# for Debugging
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. But what if I have added media urls but the images still empty ? is there any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

i hope you done all your url.py code as mention above
so image is a file so you have to request for file like this

```
def index(request.FILES, request.POST):
    images = Images.objects.all()
    context = {
              'images':images
                }
    return render(request,'home.html',context)
```

and in yours html file form tag use enctype

```
<form action="{% url 'name' %}" method'POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and remove you default from your image class if you want you image can be blank=True
no need of default in that and what i can see in your model yo didnt define path whwe you image has to be stored something like this

```
profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',default='default.png',)
```

and in your main urls.py add

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

i hope this will help and tell me if you got any error

Comment: Hello, it works with DEBUG=True, but when I set debug = False, it doesn't work anymore

Comment: what i can see you are hosting your project on heroku right maybe you will see server error 500  but if you open your web app with domain heroku after pushing the changes on heroku you will not fide any error because i also hosted some web app on heroku me also face same kind of diffculty so what i do copy and paste a copy same folder elsewhere and remove git init file heroku settings from settings.py file then i tried to run locally that file if all goes well then paste the code in main file then push it

Comment: it worked for me i hope it worked for you as well if yes then make it right